# Can I set the UIGraphics CurrentContext as a property Oriented in iOS

Tags: ios, core-graphics, rubymotion

I'm writing my application using Rubymotion rather than Objective-C/Xcode.

I find that a lot of Objective-C is written a lot more like procedural code than object oriented and I'm trying to keep my code neater and simpler than I see in most examples.

In saying that, is there any reason why I can't set the CurrentContext of a custom view as a method or property within my class? That is:

```
def drawRect(rect)
  context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
  redColor = UIColor.colorWithRed(1.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha:1.0)
  CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, redColor.CGColor)
  CGContextFillRect(context, self.bounds)

  # more drawing here ... 
end
```

Would become:

```
def drawRect(rect)
  setBackgroundRed
  # call more private methods to draw other stuff here
end

private

def context
  @context ||= UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
end

def setBackgroundRed
  CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, redColor)
  CGContextFillRect(context, bounds)
end

def redColor
  UIColor.colorWithRed(1.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha:1.0).CGColor
end
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is inadvisable to store the context pointer across calls to `drawRect`.  Each call to `drawRect` should make its own call to `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()` to get the context pointer.  From there, pass it where it needs to go.  You could do the following:

```
def drawRect(rect)
  context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
  setBackgroundRed(context)
  # call more private methods to draw other stuff here
end

private

def setBackgroundRed(context)
  CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, redColor)
  CGContextFillRect(context, bounds)
end

def redColor
  UIColor.colorWithRed(1.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha:1.0).CGColor
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer - but can you explain why it's inadvisable?

Comment: The context pointer could change between calls to `drawRect` if for instance the screen were relayed out do to device rotation or other changes.  The safe thing to do is to always get the context pointer in `drawRect`.  You could store it in an instance variable after that, but that is a style thing.

Comment: Ah - I see the difference now. I think in reality, the code I've shown here though would lazy-load the context only during the single call to drawRect. I'm not sure if that would cause an issue later or not

Comment: I realize it it a bunch of ifs, but if there is a second call to drawRect, and if the pointer has changed, your code would use the old pointer.  By making sure `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()` is called each time `drawRect` is called, you avoid that possibility.  You could accomplish the same thing with your code by setting context to `nil` at the start of `drawRect`.

Answer (score 0):

For simple scenarios like this you can just use the higher level API's, which are more OO in use. To fill a rect you don't need to drop down CoreGraphics as you can just use `UIColor` and `UIBezierPath`

```
UIColor.colorWithRed(1.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha:1.0).setFill

UIBezierPath.bezierPathWithRect(rect).fill
```